# Reiniciar Sesion en asp.net y json

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

espero me puedan ayudar con este tema, estoy trabajando un proyecto con asp.net c#, el problema es que necesito que al dar clic sobre una etiqueta  ejecute un Json y este finalice la sesión.

Les explico que es lo que hice.

Tengo clase VSesion que tiene varios métodos, pero el que me ocupa hoy es ReiniciarSesion.

```html
public static void ReiniciarSesion()
{
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();        
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Resources.SitePages.Login);
}
```

En mi Template.Master.cs llamo al método anterior de  esta forma.

```html
[WebMethod]
public static void ReiniciarSession()
{
     VSesion.ReiniciarSesion();
}
```

En el Template.Master lo llamo de esta forma..aquí es donde tengo el problema.

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Reiniciar").click("click", function() {
                ReiniciarSession();
            });
        });
        function ReiniciarSession() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TemplateSae.Master/ReiniciarSession",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Aquí la etiqueta

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="Reiniciar">
         <span>Salir</span>
      </a>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Por cierto y se me olvidó estoy utilizando

```
<script src="JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.!!

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que te da? No lo dices...

Comment: Al pinchar sobre la etiqueta <a href="" id="Reiniciar"> solo muestra el alert "error", lo que quiero es que al pinchar sobre esta etiqueta me redirija a la  página Login " HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Resources.SitePages.Login)".

Comment: Qué error muestra el alert?

Comment: Gracias por responder, el alert muestra este texto ''error''.

Comment: cambia el alert por esto: `alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown)` y prueba de nuevo a ver que te dice

Comment: Muestra el mismo texto "error:", puede ser por el hecho que el código lo tengo el MasterPage, en otros proyectos utilicé json pero los llamaba desde una página .aspx puede ser ese el error.?? verifiqué el web.config y todo está bien.

Comment: No se puede llamar a una MasterPage directamente....

Answer (score 1):

El error es que al intentar acceder al objeto `HttpContext.Current.Session`, éste tiene valor null.

Para que el objeto `Session` esté disponible en un WebMethod, debes añadir el atributo `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void ReiniciarSession()
{
     VSesion.ReiniciarSesion();
}
```